# REGEX help to capture certain values from string

Tags: regex

I am hoping someone can assist with the REGEX I am trying to do. I just want to be able to capture the first group of characters immediately after either "Job" or "Job -".

EXAMPLE:

```
Job PXDFUH34 RE443 JRA99
Job - W0WEIN12SD UIS90 TYPSOS48
```

I want to only capture PXDFUH34 and W0WEIN12SD in this example.

**UPDATE**

I was able to use this to capture what I needed.

```
\s(\w+)\s
```

However, I ran into a special character (#) that this regex doesn't like. How do I account for # now?

EXAMPLE:

```
Job R#DFUH34 RE143 JRU89
Job - W0WEIN12SD# UIS10 TTPSOS45
```

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: or just replace "- " with "" and split/substr

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
Job\b[\s-]*(\S+)
```

It means:

- Look for `Job` and a *limit* `\b` - to avoid text like `Jobless`
- and `[\s-]` spaces and hyphens `*` as many as possible you can find,
- and then group `()`
- the first word `\S+`.

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/vN8xA7/3)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
^Job\s\-?\s?\K[^\s]*\b
```

On the basis of @alanmoore comments this is the alternative

```
^Job\s\-?\s?([^\s]*)\b
```

[Working Regex](https://regex101.com/r/xH0cA5/3)

Comment: Using the `\K` you can remove the capturing groups

Comment: Nope its exactly capturing the values [Check This](https://regex101.com/r/xH0cA5/2)

Comment: I'm just saying that it would work without the capturing groups as well: _https://regex101.com/r/xH0cA5/3_

Comment: Thanks for refering  I've updated it @WashingtonGuedes

Comment: How do you know `\K` will work?  It's not that widely supported, and the OP didn't indicate which regex flavor he's using.

Comment: I've updated my answer @AlanMoore thanks for refering

Comment: I meant that you should go with the capturing group instead of `\K`.  Then it will work in any flavor.

Comment: Thanks Updated @AlanMoore. Reason behind is I'm on learning stage I've started it from this month only